# How to have default text for textbox and making it fade away only when user types something

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I am having Asp.Net Textboxes for my contact form.How can I have a default text for my textbox and make the text fade away when the user types something and not on focus , just like SO search box for example.I think it is different from textbox watermark.Any suggestions are welcome , thanks.

Comment: SO doesn't 'fade' away. It uses HTML 5 placeholder attributes.

Comment: @Phill ya I noticed that , while adding title of a question it does that i think.Can that thing be applied to Asp.net textbox

Comment: I added an answer just to clarify the attribute. Yes it can be added to an ASP.NET textbox, I'm pretty sure you can just specify it on the control, if .NET doesn't know about the attribute, it's output as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question, but rectifies part of your question.

> just like SO search box for example

The SO Search box uses [HTML 5 placeholder attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute), and the functionality you're seeing is Chrome specific.

> User agents should present this hint to the user, after having
>   stripped line breaks from it, **when the element's value is the empty
>   string and/or the control is not focused** (e.g. by displaying it inside
>   a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise).

The bold part states that the functionality should remove the placeholder text IF the value is empty and/or it's not focused.

Chrome has decided to implement this as 'when it's not empty, remove the placeholder' but if the textbox is focused and empty, the placeholder remains.

Other browsers (IE/Firefox/Opera) remove the placeholder on focus.

Comment: that means this only specific to chrome , other browsers it dissappears on focus , so I think I will go with watermark itself.Any opinions from your end.thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [AJAXTOOLKIT](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)  for this

specifically [TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax Toolkit [TextBoxWatermark Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

Comment: use jquery. [check this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/). there [more examples](https://www.google.lk/search?q=textbox+watermark+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) also

Answer (score 0):

[You can achieve using TextBoxWatermark in ajax control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)